# Android: Boolean

Tags: android, button, click, boolean

I trying to draw a circle only if the button is clicked. And to move the circle, a button has to be clicked in order to do the moving. The initial value of the bclick is false however after clicking on the button, the value of bclick becomes true all the way. How to make it such that the bclick is always set to false every time after the the circle is drawn?

My View class:

```
  @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();


                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                if (MainActivity.isButtonClicked() == true ){

                                      canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint)

                                 invalidate();
                              }

                           break;
                      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                          lastx = event.getX();
                          lasty = event.getY();
                if (MainActivity.isMoveButtonClicked() == true && Mainactivity.is ButtonCLicked() == false ){

                                      canvas.drawCircle(lastx, lasty, radius, paint)

                     invalidate();// if this is used, the moving is slow and doesnt move to the exact spot at (lastx, laxyy)
                              }

                           break;
            }
```

My MainActivity:

```
boolean bclick =false;
    boolean mbclick =false;

drawbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            bclick = true;

            }


        });

        bclick = false;

                movebutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                   mbclick = true;

            }


        });

               mbclick = false;


public static boolean isButtonClicked() {
        return bclick;
    }

public static void setButtonClicked(boolean torf)
    {
      bclick = torf;
    }

public static boolean isMoveButtonClicked() {
        return mbclick;
    }

public static void setMoveButtonClicked(boolean torf)
    {
      mbclick = torf;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a method to draw the circle and check it,

```
 if(circleIsDrawn){

      bClick = false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        x = event.getX();
        y = event.getY();


        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        if (MainActivity.isButtonClicked() == true ){

                              canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint)
                              bClick=false;
                         invalidate();
                      }

                   break;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this method however when I try to move the circle(after pressing another button), the moving of the circle became slow and does not stop at the last touched coordinates. I have updated this with more codes. Please advice thank you.